# Why are SwaggerResponse and SwaggerResponseExample complaining about HttpStatusCode?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, asp.net-core-6.0

Every example of *SwaggerResponse* and *SwaggerResponseExample* I found uses *HttpStatusCode* as is, but when I use it like this:

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(ErrorExample), Description = "Error details")]
[SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, typeof(ErrorExample))]
```

I get a compiler error complaining that it cannot convert *HttpStatusCode* from the *enum* value to *int*. The only namespace that Visual Studio offers me for resolving the *HttpStatusCode* is *System.Net*. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you just use 400  or (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest?

Comment: I suppose I can, but I am wondering why nobody seems to need to do this.